# UAS USB driver problems with Linux, but not with windows, technical explanation

Tags: linux, windows, usb-storage, uasp

I'm also getting a lot of these uas_eh_device_reset_handler errors like alread described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441668/debian-usb3-hdd-uas-i-o-errors :

```
Feb 17 01:14:13 systemname kernel: [43673.914621] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD
Feb 17 01:14:13 systemname kernel: [43673.914632] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#17 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 02 eb 65 87 68 00 00 01 00 00 00
Feb 17 01:14:13 systemname kernel: [43673.914653] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#16 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD IN
Feb 17 01:14:13 systemname kernel: [43673.914664] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#16 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 02 bb 9a ba 60 00 00 02 00 00 00
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354147] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#23 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD IN
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354160] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#23 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 04 4d 04 82 30 00 00 00 08 00 00
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354343] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#21 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD IN
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354352] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#21 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 04 4d 04 82 d0 00 00 00 08 00 00
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354711] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD IN
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.354720] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#20 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 04 4d 04 82 a8 00 00 00 08 00 00
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.394180] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
Feb 17 01:14:42 systemname kernel: [43703.505377] usb 2-2.4.3: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Feb 17 01:14:43 systemname kernel: [43703.542976] scsi host2: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

I know how to mitigate by using usb-storage driver.
I use the same drives with Windows less frequent and Windows tells that device is used as UAS. But with Windows I had never any of these issues that data transfer hang for a few seconds.

Either am using these drives too infrequent on Windows or these UAS erros don't appear with Windows. If the UAS chipsets were faulty, that device hangs from time to time, a lot of customers would complain to manufacturers like Seagate or Western Digital.

So I suppose these devices work with UAS and windows flawlessly. So why is there so many UAS trouble with Linux, whereas UAS seems to work flawlessly with windows?

EDIT: Problems occur with Raspberry PI as linux system whereas the windows system is a full featured PC. So the problem might be a hardware issue of the USB-Controller.

Comment: *"UAS USB driver problems with Linux but not with windows"* -- You're comparing Linux versus Windows, but is this with the same PC (i.e are you using a dual-boot PC)?  Or are you comparing a Linux SBC versus a Windows PC (which would be a salient detail)?  IOW is this problem really a software issue (as you frame it), or possibly a USB *host* hardware issue?  What other details have you neglected to mention?

Comment: Thank you very much. That is a very good point. I've updated the initial post. Since the USB host is a raspberry PI this may be the cause that there are problems and not with windows which runs on a fully featured PC.